# With `hypothesis`, how to generate two values that satisfy an ordering relation?

Tags: python, python-hypothesis

When writing tests using `hypothesis`, from time to time I encounter a situation that I require two distinct values which satisfy a given relation. Think of the start and end of an interval, where `start <= end` is required.

A simple example of what I would like to achieve is:

```
import datetime as dt

from hypothesis import given
from hypothesis import strategies as st


@given(
    valid_from=st.dates(),
    valid_to=st.dates(),
)
def test_dates_are_ordered(valid_from: dt.date, valid_to: dt.date):
    assert valid_from <= valid_to
```

I like that this test is very easy to read and to the point. However, it does not pass, because Hypothesis does not know about the restriction. Is there a good way to have two parameters but still ensure the values are ordered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge, there are only workarounds.

One workaround would be to use [`assume`](https://hypothesis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/details.html#hypothesis.assume), which allows to mark examples as bad. However, invalid examples would still be present in the search space, which might slow down the sampling.

```
import datetime as dt

from hypothesis import assume, given
from hypothesis import strategies as st


@given(
    valid_from=st.dates(),
    valid_to=st.dates(),
)
def test_values_are_in_order(
    valid_from: dt.date, valid_to: dt.date
) -> None:
    assume(valid_from <= valid_to)
    assert valid_from <= valid_to
```

Another option would be to sample two general examples and sort them. However, this complicates the code quite a bit, because sampling got much more complicated and the values have to be unpacked too.

```
import datetime as dt
import typing as t

from hypothesis import given
from hypothesis import strategies as st


@given(
    valid_from_to=st.lists(st.dates(), min_size=2, max_size=2)
    .map(t.cast(t.Callable[[list[dt.date]], list[dt.date]], sorted))
    .map(t.cast(t.Callable[[list[dt.date]], tuple[dt.date, ...]], tuple))
)
def test_values_are_in_order(
    valid_from_to: tuple[dt.date, dt.date]
) -> None:
    valid_from, valid_to = valid_from_to
    assert valid_from <= valid_to
```

Last and presumably also least, one could use a delta approach. Here, a start value and a delta is sampled and the end value computed from both. However, this requires that the notion of a `delta` and the notion of "adding" exists. It also might make it possible to sample invalid values, because whether or not `start + delta` is valid is much harder to tell in advance than if the end value was sampled directly. This materialises directly in the simple example below.

```
import datetime as dt

from hypothesis import given
from hypothesis import strategies as st


@given(
    valid_from=st.dates(),
    delta=st.timedeltas(min_value=dt.timedelta(1)),
)
def test_values_are_in_order(valid_from: dt.date, delta: dt.timedelta):
    # This test might cause an `OverflowError` to be raised, because
    # `valid_from` and `delta` might lead to date Python decided not to support
    # anymore.
    valid_to = valid_from + delta
    assert valid_from <= valid_to
```